# OpenGL Not Mesh Displaying

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to make my own opengl engine for learning purposes and I'm using glfw3, glew, and assimp. So far I can load models from files and display them on screen. It can also read and compile shaders from files. When I try to draw a mesh using a shader it disappears, but if I don't use a shader it shows up just fine. I think my problem might be when I'm binding the mesh data to VBO's and VAO's. It might also be how I'm loading it

Here is my Shader loading functions:

```
Shader::Shader(string vertex_path, string fragment_path) {
    Shader::success = false;

    string vertex, fragment;

    vertex = file_read_all(vertex_path);
    fragment = file_read_all(fragment_path);

    const GLchar *verCode = vertex.c_str();
    const GLchar *fraCode = fragment.c_str();

    GLuint verShader, fraShader;

    GLint success;
    GLchar log[512];

    verShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);

    glShaderSource(verShader, 1 , &verCode, NULL);
    glCompileShader(verShader);

    glGetShaderiv(verShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);

    if (!success) {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(verShader, 512, NULL, log);

        cout << "Failed to Compile Vertex Shader " << vertex_path << "!" << endl << log;
        return;
    }

    fraShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    glShaderSource(fraShader, 1, &fraCode, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fraShader);

    glGetShaderiv(fraShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);

    if (!success) {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(fraShader, 512, NULL, log);

        cout << "Failed to Compile Vertex Shader " << fragment_path << "!" << endl << log;
        return;
    }

    Shader::shader_id = glCreateProgram();

    glAttachShader(Shader::shader_id, verShader);
    glAttachShader(Shader::shader_id, fraShader);

    glLinkProgram(Shader::shader_id);

    glGetShaderiv(Shader::shader_id, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);

    glDeleteShader(verShader);
    glDeleteShader(fraShader);

    if (!success) {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(Shader::shader_id, 512, NULL, log);

        cout << "Failed to Link Shaders " << vertex_path << " and " << fragment_path << "!" << endl << log;
        return;
    }

    Shader::success = true;
    }
```

Here is my Vertex Shader program:

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;

uniform mat4 view;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = view * vec4(position, 1.0f);
}
```

Here is my function that binds mesh data to VBO's/VAO's:

```
void Mesh::bind(vector<float> vertex, vector<float> normal, vector<GLuint> indices) {
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &this->VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &this->VBO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &this->EBO);

    glBindVertexArray(this->VAO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->VBO);

    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex.size() * sizeof(float), &vertex[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->EBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices.size() * sizeof(GLuint), &indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, vertex.size() * sizeof(float), 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, normal.size() * sizeof(float), 0);

    glBindVertexArray(0);

}
```

Here is the code that draws my meshes:

```
void Mesh::Draw() {
    glBindVertexArray(this->VAO);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, this->count);
}
```

Here is my functions that loads and processes the mesh:

```
Mesh::Mesh(string path) {
    Assimp::Importer importer;

    const aiScene* scene = importer.ReadFile(path, aiProcess_Triangulate | aiProcess_JoinIdenticalVertices);

    this->process(scene);
}

void Mesh::process(const aiScene* scene) {
    vector<float> vertex, normal;
    vector<GLuint> indeces;

    this->count = 0;

    if (scene->HasMeshes()) {
        this->loaded = true;
        for (int i = 0; i != scene->mNumMeshes; i++) {
            for (int ii = 0; ii != scene->mMeshes[i]->mNumVertices; ii++) {
                vertex.push_back(scene->mMeshes[i]->mVertices[ii].x);
                vertex.push_back(scene->mMeshes[i]->mVertices[ii].y);
                vertex.push_back(scene->mMeshes[i]->mVertices[ii].z);

                normal.push_back(scene->mMeshes[i]->mNormals[ii].x);
                normal.push_back(scene->mMeshes[i]->mNormals[ii].y);
                normal.push_back(scene->mMeshes[i]->mNormals[ii].z);

                this->count++;
            }
            for (int ii = 0; ii != scene->mMeshes[i]->mNumFaces; ii++) {
                for (int iii = 0; iii != scene->mMeshes[i]->mFaces[ii].mNumIndices; iii++) {
                    indeces.push_back(scene->mMeshes[i]->mFaces[ii].mIndices[iii]);
                    indeces.push_back(scene->mMeshes[i]->mFaces[ii].mIndices[iii]);
                    indeces.push_back(scene->mMeshes[i]->mFaces[ii].mIndices[iii]);
                    this->indice_count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    this->vertex_count = this->count;
    this->bind(vertex, normal, indeces);
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code you use to draw the meshes?

Comment: Done! I don't do much for rendering

Comment: I just gave this a brief look, but I noticed at least one error: you aren't binding the connected shader program before drawing. It probably is not causing the failure, but this wouldn't work in any serious program. I suggest reading the common mistakes section on the OpenGL wiki. Also you could look at what I programmed: https://github.com/WilliamKappler/caelumGraphicsSystem/blob/master/src/CGSMesh.cpp - note this won't build right now because I'm working on changing some fundamental bits of it, but the OpenGL is sound.